# How can i use SOCKS4 proxies with aiohttp session.get?

Tags: python, proxy, aiohttp

How can i use SOCKS4 proxies with aiohttp session.get? Need some small example. Thanks!

```
session.get("http://python.org",
            proxy="socks4://1.1.1.1:4115")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aiohttp not support with sock4